# How to make the AVPlayer resize with the parent view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I've got an AVPlayerView created as proposed in Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html

So I add that UIView subclass as subview of my UIViewController.

It looks good, the video plays nicely.
However, when I minimize the view to a small window, the video does not resize with it.
It was ok, when I used MPMoviePlayerViewController, but I have a need to use AVPlayer for few reasons [muting audio, having more than one video playing at the same time etc.].

Here's my AVPlayerView implementation:

```
@implementation VideoView {

}

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}

- (AVPlayer*)player {
    return [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] player];
}

- (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player {
    [(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
}

@end
```

Here's how I create the AVPlayer:

```
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:Url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    player_vc = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
    player_vc.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    player_layer = [[VideoView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview: player_layer];

    [player_layer setPlayer:player_vc];
```

And here's the code I use for changing the frame of the parent view:

```
-(void) minimize {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = resizeFrame;
                      } completion:(void (^)(BOOL)) ^{
                 self.minimized = true;

}
```

It seems that once created with specific frame, I cannot change it to nothing else.

Could you please tell me how to make the AVPlayer layer resize with my view controller's view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayerLayers do not automatically resize with their parent views. If you're going to override a UIView's `layerClass` with AVPlayerLayer, you should also also override its `layoutSublayersOfLayer` method like so:

```
- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    [super layoutSublayersOfLayer:layer];
    if (layer == self.layer) {
       [self layer].frame = self.bounds;
    }
}
```

And in Swift 3:

```
class PlayerLayerDisplayer: UIView {

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get {
            return AVPlayerLayer.self
        }
    }

    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        guard layer == self.layer else {
            return
        }
        layer.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```